# Is there any way to have a new command start at every blank enter space for an entry?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, batch-file

I am nowhere near being competent in writing batch files so I figured someone here might have the answer.

I am looking for a way to enter a list and have the list be google searched in a new tab/ window for every entry. I would like to do this without having to do it one at a time though. To clarify if I were to put in

XYZ

ABC

123

I would want it to open chrome (or whatever it is set for) and open a tab/window and search for XYZ, open another and search for 123, and so on. I know some of the basics and enough to get it to open and search a set webpage or a variable with a single input. But can't figure out how to get it to create a new search at every line space.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. `For` loops can be used to iterate over a list of strings, `Set` can be used to take input and `start` can be used with argument to open a browser with the search term of the value of the current for loop meta variable. I suggest you open a command prompt and read the help file for each of these commands, by typing `Commandname /?` and pressing enter.

Comment: See if this extension helps: [Multiple Tabs Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multiple-tabs-search/mhbpfljoihafefdodgklimejeacejnde?hl=en).